# Where can I find the missing page sections in wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, custom-field

This is not coding question. This question is related to Word Press
I am new to Word Press. I am now trying to edit an old `word press` website from my company and i am struggling to find a solution

There are two pages in the app
example `abc.com/testing` & `abc.com/testingTwo`

What happen is that `abc.com/testing` there is a `page section` when user try to `edit page`
But when i land on `abc.com/testingTwo`and try to `edit page` there is no `page section`.

Can I add it? What the difference between these two?

Here is the side by side screen shot. I circle with red

[image]

Comment: This is not a standard feature of WordPress. You will likely need to speak to the author of your theme for further help with this.

Answer (score 0):

"Page Sections" is not a standard feature of WordPress, as Jacob says. It will have been made custom for that page template. If you look in your image, the one on the left has "Template: Page Builder" in the sidebar. I'm betting the page on the right has a different template selected in its sidebar. If you were to switch it to Page Builder, you would likely get those same fields.

Be mindful though that switching templates is what you would like to do. Most templates will be custom and certain features will only work on the appropriate template.